# ¿Por que mi menú dinámico no se actualiza al momento de cargarlo con javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy creando un menú dinámico, trae los datos correctamente a la pantalla pero no me carga con las funciones de desplegar y contraer el menú, como cargara sin ningún evento. Estoy usando la plantilla Admin LTE 2.

**Note lo siguiente:**

En la pantalla cuando inspecciono el elemento.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si le doy "ver código fuente de la página" me muestra esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Actualización 1:**

```html
    function GenerarMenus(id, esSub) {
        var menuGenrado = '';
        if (esSub) {
            menuGenrado = '<ul class="nav nav-stacked">';
        }else {
            menuGenrado = '<ul class="nav nav-stacked" id="menu">';
        }
        //Obtengo los menus papas
        ObtenerMenus(id);
        if (menus != undefined) {
            $.each(menus, function (i, v) {
                var subMenu = GenerarMenus(v.id, true);
                if (subMenu.length == 0) {
                    if(v.id_padre == 0){
                        menuGenrado += '<li class=""><a href="' + v.link + '"><i class="' + v.icono + '"></i><span> ' + v.titulo + '</span></a>';
                    }else{
                        menuGenrado += '<li class=""><a href="' + v.link + '">--><i class="' + v.icono + '"></i><span> ' + v.titulo + '</span></a>';
                    }
                } else {
                    if(v.id_padre == 0){
                        menuGenrado += '<li class=""><a href="' + v.link + '" class="dropdown-collapse"><i class="' + v.icono + '"></i><span> ' + v.titulo + '</span><i class="icon-angle-down angle-down"></i></a>';
                        menuGenrado += subMenu;
                    }else{
                        menuGenrado += '<li class=""><a href="' + v.link + '" class="dropdown-collapse">----><i class="' + v.icono + '"></i><span> ' + v.titulo + '</span><i class="icon-angle-down angle-down"></i></a>';
                        menuGenrado += subMenu;
                    }

                }
                menuGenrado += '</li>';
            });
        }
        menuGenrado += '</ul>'
        if (menuGenrado == '<ul class="nav nav-stacked"></ul>' || menuGenrado == '<ul class="nav nav-stacked"></ul>') {
            menuGenrado = '';
        }
        return menuGenrado;
    }

    var menus;
    var todoMenus;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        ObtenerSidebar();
        Contraer();
    });

    function ObtenerSidebar() {
        ObtenerTodoMenu();
        //FIN ATAJOS
        $("#main-nav").append(GenerarMenus(0, false));
    }

    function Contraer(){
        $(".nav-stacked").css("display","none");
        $("#menu").css("display","block");
    }

    function ObtenerTodoMenu() {
        //Genero el menú de ejemplo aqui
        todoMenus = [
                {
                  "id": 1,
                  "id_padre": 0,
                  "icono": "fa fa-dashboard fa-fw",
                  "link": "/",
                  "titulo": "Tablero",
                  "status": true
                },
                {
                  "id": 2,
                  "id_padre": 0,
                  "icono": "fa fa-tasks fa-fw",
                  "link": "#",
                  "titulo": "Procesos",
                  "status": true
                },
                {
                  "id": 3,
                  "id_padre": 2,
                  "icono": "fa fa-list-ol fa-fw",
                  "link": "/lotes",
                  "titulo": "Lotes",
                  "status": true
                },
                {
                  "id": 4,
                  "id_padre": 2,
                  "icono": "fa fa-eraser fa-fw",
                  "link": "/limpieza",
                  "titulo": "Limpieza",
                  "status": true
                },
                {
                  "id": 5,
                  "id_padre": 2,
                  "icono": "fa fa-stop fa-fw",
                  "link": "/paradas",
                  "titulo": "Paradas",
                  "status": true
                },
                {
                  "id": 6,
                  "id_padre": 2,
                  "icono": "fa fa-wrench fa-fw",
                  "link": "#",
                  "titulo": "Mantenimiento",
                  "status": true
                },
                {
                  "id": 7,
                  "id_padre": 6,
                  "icono": "fa fa-file-text fa-fw",
                  "link": "/planes",
                  "titulo": "Planes",
                  "status": true
                },
                {
                  "id": 8,
                  "id_padre": 6,
                  "icono": "fa fa-calendar fa-fw",
                  "link": "/calendario",
                  "titulo": "Calendario",
                  "status": true
                }
        ];
    }

    function ObtenerMenus(id) {
        menus = [];
        $.each(todoMenus, function (i, v) {
            if (v.id_padre == id) {
                menus.push(v);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Si creas dinámicamente el menú, es obvio que no estará presente cuando veas el código fuente. ¿Podrías agregar la función que genera el menú?

Comment: @MarcosGallardo listo.. agregado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error es porque en el `core` del [`Admin LTE 2`](https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html) (es decir, en el archivo `admin.min.js`) se espera que dentro del `sidebar`:

1. Solo los `li` que tienen sub-menu deben tener la clase `treeview`, es decir, `<li class="treeview"....`
2. Y solo los `ul` que sean sub-menu deben tener la clase `treeview-menu`, es decir, `<ul class="treeview-menu"...`

Comment: me funcione bien, despliega el menu, lo contrae y todo correctamente, el problema es q al hacer clic en los enlaces no manda a la url q tiene. ¿como podria hacer en ese caso?

Comment: @PabloContreras, he actualizado mi respuesta